# Why is my fetch post request being hit on breakpoint but not without?

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs

I have the following code in a React .Net application:

```
handleAdd(userId, name) {
   name = encodeURIComponent(name);
   fetch('api/deck/create/' + userId + '/' + name, {
     method: 'POST'
   }).then();
}
```

The code is called here:

```
<Form onSubmit={(id, name) => this.handleAdd(1, this.state.newDeckName)}> //1 is just a debug id
<Modal.Body>

<FormGroup controlId="formNewDeck">
<FormControl placeholder="Deck Name" value={this.state.newDeckName} onChange={this.handleDeckNameChange} name="name"/>
</FormGroup>

</Modal.Body>

<Modal.Footer>
<Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close</Button>
<Button variant="primary" type="submit">Add Deck</Button>
</Modal.Footer>
</Form>
```

If i breakpoint on it in a debugging tool and step over it, it hits my controller and correctly inserts into my database, however, if I do not breakpoint on the code and let it run through then the controller is never hit and thus nothing is inserted into the database, does anybody have an explanation for this?

Comment: weel, with these informations is impossible to know, we need more code to check when you call this function

Comment: @MateusMartins included this information now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a race condition in which the page was refreshing before the post had completed, hitting my breakpoint was giving the page time to post the request. Using `async` and `await` fixed this

```
async handleAdd(userId, name) {
   name = encodeURIComponent(name);
   await fetch('api/deck/create/' + userId + '/' + name, {
     method: 'POST'
   }).then();
}
```